# Elasticsearch Java API boolQuery

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch version 6.4.2

I succeeded to create a GET query using the REST API, now I would like to perform the same query using the JAVA api.

This is the query:

```
GET _search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "match":{
               "tags":"kpi"
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "range":{
               "@timestamp":{
                  "gt":"now-5m"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I read this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html but it is still not clear to me if this is I'm looking for and how to use it.
Consider that the query could return a lot of results that have to be processed by my java application.

Also, since I have to perform this query every 5 minutes, how can I optimize it (if possible)?

Comment: @Spara can you explain what more you need?

Comment: @Val, I think the accepted answer is not good as the other one! so I want to give him the bounty!

Comment: Gotcha, so you have your answer already then, great ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact code that works:

```
Date dateFrom = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 300 * 1000);
Date dateTo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").from(dateFrom).to(dateTo))
    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tags", "kpi"));

SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
System.out.println(query.toString());
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

logger.log(Level.INFO, "Status: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.status() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Took: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.getTook() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "IsTerminatedEarly: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.isTerminatedEarly() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "TimedOut: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.isTimedOut() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "TotalShards: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.getTotalShards() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "SuccessfulShards: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.getSuccessfulShards() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "FailedShards: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.getFailedShards() });
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Total Hits: {0}", new Object[] { searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits() });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your project is maven based, you can use elasticsearch client dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

your needed query would be:

```
val query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(
        QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timestamp").from(startDate)
    )
    .must(
        QueryBuilders.termQuery("tags", "kpi")
    )
```

and finally to execute your query you can use `client.search(query)`. `client` is a `RestHighLevelClient` type.